# Histogram with count R

Tags: r, count, bigdata, histogram, frequency

I am trying to create a histogram of my data.
My dataframe looks like this

```
x  counts
4  78
5  45
... ...
```

where x is the variable I would like to plot and counts is the number of observations. If I do hist(x) the plot will be misleading because I am not taking into account the count. I have also tried:

```
hist(do.call("c", (mapply(rep, df$x, df$count))))
```

Unfortunately this does not work because the resulting vector will be too big

```
sum(df$ount)
[1] 7943571126
```

Is there any other way I can try?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe a `barplot`?

Comment: x is a continuos variable, how can I do a bar plot?

Comment: I meant a bar plot of the counts. The data you have posted doesn't show a continuous variable.

Comment: @MarcoDeVirgilis did any of these solutions solve your issue? Feel free to add your own answer if you found another solution, or accept an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is a barplot as *@Rui Barradas* suggested. I use `ggplot` to plot data.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
counts <- c(78, 45, 50, 12, 30, 50)
df <- data.frame(x=x, counts=counts)

plt <- ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x=x, y=counts), stat="identity")
print(plt)
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: can simplify to `geom_col(aes(x=x, y=counts))`

Answer (score 2):

Since creating a new row for each repetition of x was not possible due to the size of the data, you can plot the density with a `weight` in `ggplot2` using `geom_histogram`.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:100
counts <- sample(20:200,100,T)
df <- data.frame(x,counts)

df %>% ggplot() +geom_histogram(aes(x=x, y=..density..,weight=counts))
```

[image]

compare this with just plotting the counts:

```
df %>% ggplot() +geom_histogram(aes(x=x))
```

[image]